# CSS: Increment Top Margin

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to stagger a div class in a stair type fashion, so it looks like this

```
1
 2
  3
   4
```

Edit: I want to change the top margin so each placement of the .process div is lower than the one before it. I have them floated so they'll sit side by side, but I'd also like each div to sit lower than the last.

I attempted to use `nth-child` which, of course, just added the top margin to all of the elements because it started counting at the first element and simply added the set margin to all of the divs. I know you can create a counter using CSS, but can you increment a margin using CSS?

**CSS**

```
.process {
    float: left;
    width: 20%;
}

.process:nth-child(1n+2) {
    margin-top: 1em;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<!-- #dprocess -->
<div id="dprocess">


    <!-- .process -->
    <div class="process">

        <p>Name Goes Here</p>

    <!-- /.process -->
    </div>


    <!-- .process -->
    <div class="process">

        <p>Name Goes Here</p>

    <!-- /.process -->
    </div>


    <!-- .process -->
    <div class="process">

        <p>Name Goes Here</p>

    <!-- /.process -->
    </div>


    <!-- .process -->
    <div class="process">

        <p>Name Goes Here</p>

    <!-- /.process -->
    </div>


    <!-- .process -->
    <div class="process">

        <p>Name Goes Here</p>

    <!-- /.process -->
    </div>


<!-- /#dprocess -->
</div>
```

Comment: I don't understand how adding a top margin is going to have the effect of indenting the divs.

Comment: I want to change the top margin so each placement of the .process div is lower than the one before it. I have them floated so they'll sit side by side, but I'd also like each div to sit lower than the last.

Comment: OK.  The nth-child selector will just allow to select specific element which are nth child of a parent and allow you to apply a common rule to them. In other words it doesn't allow you to apply n*1em margin to the elements.

Comment: I realized that after I attempted to use that particular method. It seems to me there should be a way to increment the margin without adding additional classes or using jQuery. Of course, I may be wrong.

Comment: Yes, using javascript, it would be pretty trivial.

Comment: I swear I have seen buggy html pages in buggy browsers creating unwanted staircases in the old times.

Comment: Aye, I'll use javascript for now and do more research. Hope maybe someone here might know a way.

Comment: @biziclop Exactly. I was trying to reproduce that with placement, but so far I haven't managed.

Comment: Do you have an upper limit for the number of blocks?

Comment: Are we talking about a small number of div's (like the four you show) or tens or even hundreds of div elements like this?

Comment: The blocks will be five in total set at 20% width in a 100% relatively placed div.

Comment: Bad example: http://jsfiddle.net/C4TWc/ Better: http://jsfiddle.net/C4TWc/1/

Comment: Oh, @biziclop, that's perfect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you have a very limited set of elements it is okay to use copypasting:

http://jsfiddle.net/C4TWc/1/

HTML:

```
<div>name</div>
<div>name</div>
<div>name</div>
<div>name</div>
<div>name</div>
```

CSS:

```
div {
    float: left;
    width: 20%;
}

div:first-child + div { margin-top: 2em; }
div:first-child + div + div { margin-top: 4em; }
div:first-child + div + div + div { margin-top: 6em; }
div:first-child + div + div + div + div { margin-top: 8em; }
div:first-child + div + div + div + div + div { margin-top: 10em; }
```

Comment: Yeah, that's a very generic solution you have there, and you only need <number of divs> CSS rules to achieve it! (sorry if I sounded stingy, but seriously, that solution would break horribly in the long term).

Comment: It's true, but OP wants to layout exactly 5 elements.

Comment: Today, tomorrow he might want 42.

Comment: Today and tomorrow and the following day I only want 5 elements. It's for a set section that doesn't change and won't change in the future without being completely redesigned in a different layout.

I'm saving your version, though @Truth because I have another section that requires multiple staggers with an unknown number. I'll use yours there.

Answer (score 5):

Have you considered changing the markup?

```
<div>
    1
    <div>
        2
        <div>
            3
            <div>
                4
                <div>
                    5
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<style type="text/css">
    * {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }
    div {
        margin-left: 10px;
    }
</style>
```

That markup also seems more suited for the job (given the hirarchial structure you want).

Comment: No, I hadn't thought about using nested lists, but it's definitely a solution I can work with.

Answer (score 1):

Another possible way (breaks very easily):

http://jsfiddle.net/C4TWc/2/

HTML:

```
<div>name</div>
<div>name</div>
<div>name</div>
<div>name</div>
<div>name</div>
```

CSS:

```
div {
    display: block;
}

div ~ div:before {
    content: '';
    width:  20%;
    height: 2em;
    float: left;
}
```

Comment: I see that, it does break easy. I'll stick to the other solution you gave me.

Answer (score 0):

There are several suggestions for alternative methods, but the answer to your original question is "no". CSS Counters are functions intended to be used within the Content property.  [Source](https://drafts.csswg.org/css2/#counters%E2%91%A0)

Additionally, CSS variables and properties are generally not incremental without assistance. If you want a repurposable solution that works for an indeterminate number of divs, your best bet is to use SASS or JavaScript.