# CSS increasing margin on successive list elements

Tags: html, css

I'd like to create a list where each successive element has a greater margin than the previous one. 
You can see what I want to achieve here: [Example with fixed margin](https://jsfiddle.net/95b2oaeg/)

So, let's take a simple list

```
<ul>
  <li class="a">First element</li>
  <li class="b">Second element</li>
  <li class="c">Third element</li>
</ul>
```

I could give each element a class and set an increased margin to each class, like this

```
.a {
  margin-left: 10px;
}

.b {
 margin-left: 20px;
}

.c {
  margin-left: 30px;
}
```

I'd like to be able to do that, however, without specifying directly the margin for each element, using instead a fixed increment that is automatically applied to each additional list element

Is there any intelligent way to achieve this with css?

Comment: There feels like should be a way to do with, like with counter increments and maybe calc(), but from what I understand it's not possible without JavaScript.

Comment: See : [CSS: Increment Top Margin](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11675993/css-increment-top-margin) & [Set margin (indent) based on counter value in CSS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13430686/set-margin-indent-based-on-counter-value-in-css)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Obvious answer first, this is what heirarchy is for, so most will recommend using nested uls:

```html
<ul>
  <li>001
    <ul>
      <li>002
        <ul>
          <li>003</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Otherwise, I think you will have to turn to using JS or CSS `calc` if it has enough support for your needs.